# How do you install a pod's sub spec without installing the whole pod?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I just want one subspec of one library, for example, the nimbus podspec is as follows:

`pod search Nimbus`

```
-> Nimbus (1.0.0)

An iOS framework whose growth is bounded by O(documentation).
- Homepage: http://docs.nimbuskit.info/index.html
- Source:   https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus.git
- Versions: 1.0.0, 0.9.3, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9.0 [master repo]
- Sub specs:
    - Nimbus/Core (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/Badge (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/CSS (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/AttributedLabel (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/Interapp (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/Launcher (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/Models (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/NetworkControllers (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/NetworkImage (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/Overview (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/PagingScrollView (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/Photos (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/Operations (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/Operations/JSON (1.0.0)
    - Nimbus/WebController (1.0.0)
```

I just want to install the Nimbus/core, what should the `podfile` contain?

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 18):

just use following line in your pod spec

```
pod 'Nimbus/Core', '= 1.0.0'
```

Complete pod spec sample:

```
platform :iOS,'6.0'

pod 'Nimbus/Core', '= 1.0.0'
```